# sending datasets with ksoap

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

In my app I have to send a big dataset back to our server for processing. I am using `ksoap` for all my requests to pull stuff from the server with your normal xml properties and attributes but in the one call I have to use a dataset to send information.

Is there anything in the `ksoap` library for android that makes this whole process easier?

basically right now I am just constructing this huge string with all these header,tags and a shcema

example:

```
String header = "<mmAps diffgr:id=\"mmApps"+String.valueOf(count)+"\" msdata:rowOrder=\"0\" diffgr:hasChanges=\"inserted\">\n";
String ecmmaID = "<ECMMAID>"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Apparatus.APP_ECMMAID))+"</ECMMAID>\n";
etc..

String datasetToSend = header+ecmmaID+....;
```

and then I would make the request passing in the big string

Please tell me there is some sot of easier way to do this.

Also changing away from data sets is not a possibility since its out of my control

Comment: Have you considered using json instead of ksoap? it's a lot easier

Comment: @YasmineGreenApple as I said this is out of my control so I have to use a dataset

Answer (score 2):

JSON is the best option that you can use easily with KSOAP. This would be structured and far more better than your generated string.

**1. Make identical Model class in android and your server (C#.Net, Java, etc.)**

```
// In Android
class MyData {
    String someThing;
    public getSomeThing() {}
    //...
}
```

**2. Encode that dataset to JSONArray in android using model class**

```
// Create JSON Objects in loop for entire dataset
JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
jo.add(myData.getSomthing());
// Add all JSON Objects in JSONArray
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
jArray.add(jo);
```

**3. Send this JSON as string using KSOAP**

```
String toSendViaKsoap = jArray.toString();
```

**4. Decode that string from json to list of model class on server.**

Depending on your server language, decode that string and create objects of similar class of step 1 in native language here, and do whatever you want.
If you have .NET server application, there are lots of free libraries to dacode json inclulding builting json support as well. but I will prefer [this](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) one.

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: well like I said I have no control over the server so JSON is not an option